# Reporting Services with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, reporting-services

I am using SQL Reporting services to hit a WCF web service.

My query is:

```
    <Query>
<Method Name="GetADTHistory" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<Parameters>
       <Parameter Name="personId"><DefaultValue>7885323F-DE8D-47E5-907D-2991C838FF3E</DefaultValue></Parameter>
   </Parameters>
</Method>
<SoapAction>
http://tempuri.org/IResidentServiceFrontEnd/GetADTHistory
</SoapAction>
</Query>
```

My implementation is

```
public List<ResidentDataTypes.Person> GetADTHistory(Guid personId)
        {
            using (ResidentDataTypes.MyEntities entity = new ResidentDataTypes.MyEntities ())
            {
                var person = (from a in entity.People.Include("ResidentAdts")
                              where a.PersonId == personId
                              select a);

                if (person.Count() > 0)
                {
                    return person.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new List<Person>();
                }

            }
        }
```

This works fine if there are 2 or more ADT records. Reporting services correctly sees all the fields in the database.  However if there is only 1 ADT record reporting services sees the 'Person' columns but none of the ADT records.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have an eager/lazy load issue. I suggest you to execute and test the query with linqpad to check if it really includes the ResidentAdts in the case of single record.

I also recommend you to check this thread: [Linq to Entities Include Method Not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794283/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-loading)

Adding the "Linq" tag to your question would also helpful.

Comment: I have verfied that ADTs load via SQL profiler and I can see the objects within a watch window of Visual studio prior to the function returning.

Comment: Then, it may be related to your report definition and how to use the ADT records in the report structures. I dont think it is a serialization problem but it may also worth to check if the data serialized correctly with a custom client which call the services. You may also use a tool like Fiddler to check the data recieved from server if it is not encrypted.

Comment: When I use the WCF Test Client, it hangs on this method.  It works for other methods on the same service.  I will look into using Fiddler.