# Problem with slow query using predicate builder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, predicatebuilder

This question takes no time at all to execute, but if I uncomment the last line it takes 5 seconds.  How could this affect the query that much? It's almost the exact same query.

```
return db.Parties.Where(predicate).Select(p => new SearchResult
{
    adressPerson = p.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(m => m.contact_type == "H").streetname,
    //adressOrg = p.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(m => m.contact_type == "W").streetname
});
```

How do I locate the problem?

Here's what the predicate looks like:

```
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.surname.EndsWith(keyword));
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.lastname.EndsWith(keyword));
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.organisation.EndsWith(keyword));
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contacts.Any(c => c.streetname.EndsWith(keyword)));
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Memberships.Any(m => m.Congregation.congregation_name.EndsWith(keyword)));
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.PartyCategories.Any(m => m.Category.category_name.EndsWith(keyword) || m.Category.category_code.EndsWith(keyword)));
```

*I know it's stupid to post a lot of code but here's the SQL-query anyway. Any clues?*

```
SELECT (
    SELECT [t6].[streetname]
    FROM [dbo].[Contact] AS [t6]
    WHERE ([t6].[contact_type] = @p7) AND ([t6].[party_id] = [t0].[party_id])
    ) AS [adressPerson], (
    //SELECT [t7].[streetname]
    //FROM [dbo].[Contact] AS [t7]
    //WHERE ([t7].[contact_type] = @p8) AND ([t7].[party_id] = [t0].[party_id])
    //) AS [adressOrg]
FROM [dbo].[Party] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[surname] LIKE @p0) OR ([t0].[lastname] LIKE @p1) OR ([t0].[organisation] LIKE @p2) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Contact] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t1].[streetname] LIKE @p3) AND ([t1].[party_id] = [t0].[party_id])
    )) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Membership] AS [t2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Congregation] AS [t3] ON [t3].[congregation_id] = [t2].[congregation_id]
    WHERE ([t3].[congregation_name] LIKE @p4) AND ([t2].[party_id] = [t0].[party_id])
    )) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[PartyCategories] AS [t4]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [t5] ON [t5].[category_id] = [t4].[category_id]
    WHERE (([t5].[category_name] LIKE @p5) OR ([t5].[category_code] LIKE @p6)) AND ([t4].[party_id] = [t0].[party_id])
))
```

**SOLVED**
Turned out that the INNER JOIN in the last select statement didn't work. So I changed the last line of the predicate to:

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.PartyCategories
    .GroupJoin(db.Categories, b => b.category_id, c => c.category_id, (b, c) => new { b, c })
    .SelectMany(c => c.c.DefaultIfEmpty(), (c, b) => new { c.c, b })
    .Any(m => m.b.category_name.EndsWith(keyword) || m.b.category_code.EndsWith(keyword)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I locate the problem?

As always, the way to find out is to look at the generated SQL, and run it through SQL profiler.

My guess is that it changes from a simple inner join when you're only interested in a single contact type into something rather more complicated, or possibly even an "N+1-selects" problem. Anyway, looking into the SQL should make it a lot clearer.

Comment: I guess this was the problem in a way. When I rewrote the predicate it turned the SQL into a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Niklas: Right - and did you see what the SQL profiler did in the two different cases?

Comment: @Niklas: Not sure, to be honest... it feels like if this is an important enough concern to warrant profiling, you should probably have at least one "full" licence :)

Answer (score 0):

Niklas,

I would look at the SQL as suggested to see what's happening at that level. I'd also suggest doing an `.Include()` on the initial linq query as this will eagerly load the `Contacts, Memberships and PartyCategories` entities. Otherwise, you definately will be lazy loading on an N+1 select pattern. Check out the following link for .included usage:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx

[Linq-to-entities - Include() method not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794283/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-loading)

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Entity_Framework_and_Lazy_Loading.aspx

cheers...

Comment: hi niklas, ahh then none of the above would make any difference. .Include() is ef only. i would however say that on big datasets, the excessive use of the like statement on non indexed fields will have a major performance impact.

Comment: Thanks anyway! This will probably come in handy when I switch to EF later.