# Entity Framework: Include and Explicitly defined foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq-to-entities - Include() method not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794283/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-loading)

I have something **like** this

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In context I have:

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

But when I try to use it like this:

```
List<Product> foo = (from p in Context.Products 
                     where p.Category.Name = "something" 
                     select p).ToList();

Product first = foo.First();
```

I get the value of Product.CategoryId set but null inside Category

Note: I've tried with 'Context.Products.Include("Category")' and doesn't work.

This works (Category is loaded into first):

```
List<Product> foo = (from p in Context.Products 
                     where p.Category.Name = "something" 
                     select p).ToList();

Product first = foo.First();

List<Category> categories = Context.Categories.ToList();
```

So do I have to load category everytime? Why is include not working?

Comment: `Include("Category")` should load the category. Maybe your real code is still essentially different from the example. Do you see a SQL query with a join?

Comment: Gustavo, I don't agree with closing this question because the "duplicate" is about `Include` in combination with `join` and the issue is well over three years old. Are you using a very old version of EF or can you confirm what I asked above? We might vote to reopen your question if it's still an issue.