# LinqToEntitiesDomainService Include

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Why is it that the first IQueryable below includes the Customer entries in the results while the latter doesn't?

```
public IQueryable<Purchase> GetPurchases()
{

    // this works - includes Customer in results
    return this.ObjectContext.Purchases.Include("Customer");

    // this doesn't
    return from purchase in this.ObjectContext.Purchases.Include("Customer")
           join cust in this.ObjectContext.Customers 
           on purchase.CustomerId equals cust.CustomerId
           select purchase;                   

}
```

In my project I have a considerably more complex query that requires a join, and it seems odd to me that one form of the query works while the other doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq-to-entities - Include() method not loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794283/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-loading)

Comment: thank you, indeed it is a duplicate.

Comment: I think you can close question now

Comment: needs 3 more votes before I can close.