# Entity Framework will not load related entity when using .Include unless the context knows about the related entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, include

Using Entity Framework 6.1.x with the default User (ApplicationUser) model that is included when starting a basic Asp.NET MVC project. Related to the question are two more entities: Customer and Organization (both work in progress). Below is the Customer class.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UniqueId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Organization can for all purposes be considered a minimal entity with a single Id property.

The following code will not include Organization in the customers collection:

```
var customers = this.context.Customers.Include(c => c.Organization)
    .Join(this.context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId), c => c.Organization.Id, u => u.Organization.Id, (c, u) => c)
    .ToList();
```

However, it will work when I either add `virtual` to the Customer.Organization property, or if I let the context know about the organizations by running `this.context.Organizations.ToList()`.

Finally, based on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) that talks about how `.Include()` will not work if the query changes shape after `.Include()` has been issued, I wrote the following code:

```
var customers = this.context.Customers
    .Join(this.context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId), c => c.Organization.Id, u => u.Organization.Id, (c, u) => c)
    .AsQueryable<Customer>().Include(c => c.Organization)
    .ToList();
```

The last code snippet works, so I guess I can use that.

However, it is not as pretty as the first code, but more importantly, I really want to understand why the first code does not work. Is it because of "the shape of the query" is changing? If so, how come it works when I let the context know about the organizations before calling the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lazy Loading

Adding `virtual` keyword (with the `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true`) will enable lazy loading.

When the context is still alive, any programmatically access to navigation property will automatically load the reference if it hasn't been loaded yet.

## Local Data

Calling `context.Organizations.ToList()` will load all organizations from database to memory (in this case [Local data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)). And since it is loaded in the same context, when Local data is updated, all references that are being tracked will be updated too.

## Include Limitation

To make your initial code works, you need to change the join result from

```
(c, u) => c
```

to

```
(c, u) => new { Customer = c, Organization = c.Organization }
```

but the `customers` result will change into anonymous type collection that contains `Customer` property. To return the `Customer`, you need to have additional code like.

```
.ToList().Select(c => c.Customer).ToList();
```

The first query will look like.

```
var customers = this.context.Customers.Include(c => c.Organization)
    .Join(this.context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId), c => c.Organization.Id, u => u.Organization.Id, (c, u) => new { Customer = c, Organization = c.Organization })
    .ToList().Select(c => c.Customer).ToList();
```

[The article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) that you gave was written by the guy who answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794283/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-loading).

Comment: I see. I've opted to disable lazy loading, so virtual isn't an option. The include limitation section of your answer was very helpful and did solve the issue (although the use of ".Include(c => c.Organization)" is no longer required). It's not pretty though, but not much that can be done about that.